# Solving Inverse Integral

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, definite-integrals

Evaluate

> $$\int^{1/{\sqrt{3}}}_{-1/{\sqrt{3}}} \frac{x^4}{1-x^4}\cos^{-1}\frac{2x}{1+x^2} \mathrm{d}x
> $$

---

The Solution:
$$\begin{align}I&=\int _{ -1/{ \sqrt { 3 } } }^{ 1/{ \sqrt { 3 } } }{ \frac { { x }^{ 4 } }{ 1-{ x }^{ 4 } } \cos ^{ -1 }{ \frac { 2x }{ 1+{ x }^{ 2 } } } } {\rm d}x\tag{1}\end{align}$$
Put $t=-x$:
$$\begin{align}I&=\int _{ -1/{ \sqrt { 3 } } }^{ 1/{ \sqrt { 3 } } }{ \frac { { t }^{ 4 } }{ 1-{ t }^{ 4 } } \left(\pi -\cos ^{ -1 }{ \frac { 2t }{ 1+{ t }^{ 2 } } } \right) } {\rm d}t\tag{2}\\
 2I&=\pi \int _{ -1/{ \sqrt { 3 } } }^{ 1/{ \sqrt { 3 } } }{ \frac { { x }^{ 4 } }{ 1-{ x }^{ 4 } } } {\rm d}x\tag{3}\\
I&=\frac { \pi }{ 2 } \int _{ -1/{ \sqrt { 3 } } }^{ 1/{ \sqrt { 3 } } }{ \frac { { x }^{ 4 }-1+1 }{ 1-{ x }^{ 4 } } } {\rm d}x=\frac { \pi }{ 2 } \int _{ -1/{ \sqrt { 3 } } }^{ 1/{ \sqrt { 3 } } }{ \left(-1+\frac { 1 }{ 1-{ x }^{ 4 } }\right) } {\rm d}x\tag{4}\\
 I&=\frac { \pi }{ 2 } \int _{ -1/{ \sqrt { 3 } } }^{ 1/{ \sqrt { 3 } } }{ \left(-1+\frac { 1-{ x }^{ 2 }+1+{ x }^{ 2 } }{ 2(1-{ x }^{ 2 })(1+{ x }^{ 2 }) } \right)} {\rm d}x\tag{5}\\
 I&=\frac { \pi }{ 2 } \int _{ -1/{ \sqrt { 3 } } }^{ -1/{ \sqrt { 3 } } }{ \left(-1+\frac { 1 }{ 2(1-{ x }^{ 2 }) } +\frac { 1 }{ 2(1+{ x }^{ 2 }) } \right)} {\rm d}x\tag{6}\\
 I&=\frac { \pi }{ 2 } \left[ \frac{-2}{ \sqrt { 3 } } +\frac { 1 }{ 2 } \ln { \left| \frac { 1+\sqrt { 3 } }{ 1-\sqrt { 3 } } \right| } +\frac { \pi }{ 6 } \right]\tag{7} \\
 I&=\frac { \pi }{ 4 } \ln { (2+\sqrt { 3 } ) } +\frac { { \pi }^{ 2 } }{ 12 } -\frac { \pi }{ \sqrt { 3 } } \tag{8}\end{align}\\ $$

Comment: Note that $\cos (\pi -y)=-\cos y$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$A=\cos ^{ -1 }{ \frac { 2x }{ 1+{ x }^{ 2 } } } $$
Now $t=-x$ or $x=-t$:
$$A=\arccos\frac{-2t}{1+(-t)^2}=\arccos\left(-\frac{2t}{1+t^2}\right)$$
Now:
$$\arccos(-x)=\pi-\arccos(x)\tag{*}$$
So
$$A=\pi-\arccos\frac{2t}{1+t^2}$$

---

And:
$$I=\int^{1/{\sqrt{3}}}_{-1/{\sqrt{3}}} \frac{x^4}{1-x^4}\cos^{-1}\frac{2x}{1+x^2} \mathrm{d}x\\
I=\int^{1/{\sqrt{3}}}_{-1/{\sqrt{3}}} \frac{x^4}{1-x^4}\left(\pi-\cos^{-1}\frac{2x}{1+x^2}\right) \mathrm{d}x$$
Adding:
$$2I=\int^{1/{\sqrt{3}}}_{-1/{\sqrt{3}}} \frac{x^4}{1-x^4}\left(\cos^{-1}\frac{2x}{1+x^2} +\pi-\cos^{-1}\frac{2x}{1+x^2} \right)\mathrm{d}x\\
2I=\int^{1/{\sqrt{3}}}_{-1/{\sqrt{3}}} \frac{x^4}{1-x^4}(\pi)\mathrm{d}x$$

---

> $(^*)$**Proof:** $$\cos(\pi-x)=-\cos x\qquad x\in[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$$ Put $$x=\arccos t\qquad t\in[-1,1]$$ So $$\cos(\pi-\arccos t)=-\cos\arccos t=-t$$ Take inverse cosine both sides:
>  $$\arccos(\cos(\pi-\arccos t))=\arccos(-t)\implies \pi-\arccos t=\arccos(-t)$$

Comment: @BetterWorld by definition arccos is inverse of cos. So arccos(cos(something))=something. (YEs we need to take care that something is $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$)

Comment: @BetterWorld Adding. I got it.

Comment: @BetterWorld Add (1) and (2) in your post

Comment: @BetterWorld to remove the arccos term.